# Change ListView position dynamically

Tags: java, android

I'm doing this Application where I dynamically change a ListView Size like in the following code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParam = new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
sucs.setLayoutParams(myListView);
```

But when I do this, the ListView appears on top of the view. Is there any way where I can place it below the textview where it is supposed to be?

Thanks in advance!

**EDITED:**
Here´s my xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sucursales_empresa"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/direccion_empresa"
    android:background="@drawable/barra"
    android:text="@string/sucursales"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/sucursalesEmpresaList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/sucursales_empresa"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Comment: what else do you need me to post?

Comment: There is an option to place a component after/below another component. (you can search for android:layout_below). Check out this link - http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/

Comment: Why don't you try `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParam = new   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            sucs.setLayoutParams(myListView);` instead of `FILL_PARENT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add rule for listview LayoutParams like this..

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                
params1.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.textview);
listview.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, view.getId());

  view.setLayoutParams(params);
  ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.viewgroup);
  parentView.addView(mylsitview);
```